# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9' Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

Tags: asp-classic, sql-injection, parameterized-query

I've got an old website that is using ASP Classic and I have recently been asked remove the SQL injection attack threat. I'm trying to use parameterized queries, but it's all a little above my head.

here is my code:

```vbs
<% whatSector = request.querystring("whatSector")%>

    <%  adoCon.Open cString
        dim rs_client
        if whatSector="" then
    strSQL="SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY alphabet"
    else

    Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.COMMAND")

    strCmd1 = "SELECT * FROM clients Where industrySector=? ORDER BY alphabet"

    Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = adoCon
        objCommand.CommandText = strCmd1
        objCommand.CommandType = adCmdText

    Set param1 = objCommand.CreateParameter ("whatSector",adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
    param1.value = whatSector
    objCommand.Parameters.Append(param1)
    Set rs_client = objCommand.Execute()

    end if 
    set rs_client = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs_client.open strSQL,adoCon

%>
```

This seemed to work for me on another page (except for some reason I had to remove a recordCount thing I was using for paging), but I'm getting the following error on this page:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
>
> /clients/clientspotlight_list.asp, line 50

Line 50 - is the rs_client.open at the end of the above code snippet.

I have used

```
    <!-- METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" NAME="Microsoft ADO Type Library" UUID="{00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}" -->
```

for adovbs.inc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your parameter names are malformed. Try changing your assignment of **strCmd1** to:

```
strCmd1 = "SELECT * FROM clients Where industrySector=@whatSector ORDER BY alphabet"
```

Then change the assignment of **param1** to:

```
Set param1 = objCommand.CreateParameter ("@whatSector",adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. 

I should say that I get the error when I land on the page with something in the query string.  So if I just go to:

      page.asp

the page works fine.   but if I go to 

      page.asp?whatSector=something

I get the above error.

Answer (score 1):

OK.. problem solved

I moved the last two lines after the end if

```
set rs_client = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs_client.open strSQL,adoCon
```

to above before the ELSE

yes,  it was that simple..  a logic mis-flow, pointed out to me by my friend - who read my problem here, and pointed me in the right direction elsewhere ..

Thanks dmarietta :-)